# Where clause not being adhered to

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following sql query which I found on the web, if it worked correctly it would be perfect, but it's not adhering to the where clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM Chicken AS a,
     (SELECT MIN(Temp) AS mini, MAX(Temp) AS maxi
      FROM Chicken
     ) AS m
WHERE m.maxi = a.Temp AND `Location` = "Outside" OR m.mini = a.Temp AND `Location` = "Outside"
ORDER BY `a`.`Time` DESC Limit 1
```

what is happening is that it's taking the lowest and the highest temperature regardless of location. I need it to find the lowest and highest temperature for the location 'Outside'.

Can anyone help?

Comment: So put a `WHERE` clause in the subquery.

Comment: Don't mix `AND` and `OR` without parentheses.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve (and how that's different from the output you're actually getting with this query)?

Comment: My table looks like this
(`ID`, `Location`, `Time`, `Temp`, `Hum`) VALUES
(1609, 'Inside', '2016-12-03 08:43:12', 7.00, 100),
(1610, 'Outside', '2016-12-03 09:43:13', 7.00, 1),
(1611, 'Inside', '2016-12-03 09:43:14', 6.00, 100),
(1612, 'Outside', '2016-12-03 10:43:15', 7.00, 1),
etc...
I am trying to get the lowest and highest temperature record for Outside and then I will rerun the query for Inside

James

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Chicken AS a,
     (SELECT MIN(Temp) AS mini, MAX(Temp) AS maxi
      FROM Chicken
     ) AS m
WHERE (m.maxi = a.Temp AND `Location` = "Outside") OR (m.mini = a.Temp AND `Location` = "Outside")
ORDER BY `a`.`Time` DESC Limit 1
```

Try this may be its works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but that has the same problem as the original query, it's selecting the lowest and highest temperature regardless of the Location.